# Why doesn't my new shower cartridge allow water flow?

Tags: plumbing

My dad and I are trying to replace a Delta shower cartridge behind the nob. When we take off the cartridge and just let the water flow in from the pipe it has high pressure but as soon as you put in the old or new cartridge the water trickles out of the faucet and doesn't even have enough pressure to reach the shower head.

We have cleaned out those pipes and the blockage happens when you put in the new or old cartridge. The cartridges fit exactly and are actual delta replacement parts. If you need any additional pictures or videos please ask because we are in desperate need.

[image: Cartridge]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How about a picture of the old and/or new cartridge?

Comment: The one above is the old cartridge which worked before we took it out and doesn't now. We have tried multiple new ones and have returned all. This is also a project with my dad so I can't take the old one out of the wall right now because he is not with me.

Comment: Are you sure you're putting it back in the right way? They only fit one way but some people like to force things. When you turn it on, does the handle turn as much as it did before replacing the cartridge?  When you turn it on without the cartridge, did you test both hot and cold water individually? Is the cartridge one or two pieces?  When you have it apart, take a picture of the inside of the faucet. Also take a picture of the cartridge.

Comment: I will have to take these pictures tomorrow. And yes I put it the right way. The handle turns the exact same way it did prior. Without the cartridge and you turn on the master water you can feel hot and cold coming out. How do I test individual? Copper pipes straight into the water spook canvas sn

Comment: I accidentally didnt finish the previous comment, as I was, the pipes are copper and soldered to the water appliances. Also comment above auto corrected some thing please ignore

Comment: if the auto correct messed up the comment, then delete the comment and post again

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms you describe are those of installing it upside down. It may APPEAR to work correctly because the handle turns in the same manner, but is in fact not.

Comment: The only thing that could happen if it's upside down is that the hot will come first when you open the valve.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Changing the cartridge releases trapped dirt, which may have clogged a filter in the shower head.

I tried everything in making my new shower cartridge work but nothing! NO water flow or just sprinkles. So I return the first cartridge and bought a new one to replace it but same thing, no water flow!

Apparently nobody has a good answer to something so simple, but just to make sure I decided to check the shower head for any obstruction: and there was a tiny filter that was clogged completely by dirt pushed up to it from  replacing the old cartridge!

Unscrewing the shower head will show the tiny filter, clean it and enjoy good water flow.